# Setting up slapd via Ansible debops.slapd

Tags: ldap, ansible, slapd

I'm trying to setup a `slapd` service on an Ubuntu 16 machine using Ansible and `debops.slapd` but cannot get a working authentication up and running.

My playbook file looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: "{{hosts}}"
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - role: debops.slapd
      slapd_domain: 'development.local'
      slapd_pki: false
      slapd_config_admin_password: 'passwords/ldap-admin.password'
      slapd_basedn_admin_password: 'passwords/ldap-admin.password'
      slapd_ldapscripts: true
      slapd_ldap_security_default: []
      slapd_anonymous_bind: true
```

The `passwords/ldap-admin.password` file:

```
yoh7eQue9Ki0aitee5uquaichuteo0ti
```

[image: Directory structure]

When I launch Ansible via the command line `ansible-playbook install-devserver-ubuntu.yml --ask-sudo-pass --extra-vars "hosts=ubuntu"` the installation proceeds correctly and `slapd` is correctly installed on the target machine:

```
PLAY [ubuntu] ************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.secret : Create secret directories on Ansible Controller] ***************************************

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure domain for OpenLDAP in debconf] ***********************************************
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=slapd/domain)
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=shared/organization)

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure database backend for OpenLDAP in debconf] *************************************
changed: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Install OpenLDAP packages] **************************************************************
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=[u'slapd', u'ldap-utils', u'python-ldap'])

TASK [debops.slapd : Install helper scripts] *****************************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Copy custom LDAP schema files] **********************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Load custom LDAP schema files] **********************************************************
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=/usr/local/etc/ldap/schema/ldapns.ldif)
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=/usr/local/etc/ldap/schema/openssh-lpk.ldif)

TASK [debops.slapd : Check if administrator password hash exists] ********************************************
ok: [ubuntu -> localhost]

TASK [debops.slapd : Read hash of config administrator password] *********************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Generate config administrator password] *************************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Save hash of config administrator password] *********************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Set config administrator password] ******************************************************
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=(censored due to no_log))
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=(censored due to no_log))

TASK [debops.slapd : Check if BaseDN administrator password hash exists] *************************************
ok: [ubuntu -> localhost]

TASK [debops.slapd : Read hash of BaseDN administrator password] *********************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Generate BaseDN administrator password] *************************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Save hash of BaseDN administrator password] *********************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Set BaseDN administrator] ***************************************************************
ok: [ubuntu] => (item=(censored due to no_log))
changed: [ubuntu] => (item=(censored due to no_log))

TASK [debops.slapd : Create path to LDAP password file in secrets] *******************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Save BaseDN administrator password for Ansible] *****************************************
changed: [ubuntu -> localhost]

TASK [debops.slapd : Add OpenLDAP system user to additional groups] ******************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Check if TLS certificate is configured] *************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Create random temporary directory for ldif file] ****************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Prepare temporary ldif file] ************************************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Restart slapd (first time only)] ********************************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure TLS certificates (first time only)] *******************************************
skipping: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure TLS certificates] *************************************************************
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcTLSCipherSuite', 'value': u'SECURE256:-VERS-SSL3.0'})
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcTLSCertificateFile', 'value': u'/etc/pki/system/default.crt'})
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcTLSDHParamFile', 'value': u''})
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcTLSCertificateKeyFile', 'value': u'/etc/pki/system/default.key'})
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcTLSCACertificateFile', 'value': u'/etc/pki/system/CA.crt'})

TASK [debops.slapd : Allow anonymous bind] *******************************************************************
ok: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcDisallows', 'value': u'bind_anon'})
ok: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcRequires', 'value': u'authc'})

TASK [debops.slapd : Allow anonymous bind (frontend)] ********************************************************
ok: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcRequires', 'value': u'authc'})

TASK [debops.slapd : Deny anonymous bind, require authentication] ********************************************
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcDisallows', 'value': u'bind_anon'})
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcRequires', 'value': u'authc'})

TASK [debops.slapd : Deny anonymous bind, require authentication (frontend)] *********************************
skipping: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcRequires', 'value': u'authc'})

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure LDAP connection security] *****************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure LDAP indices] *****************************************************************
changed: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure LDAP Access Control List] *****************************************************
changed: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Set slapd log level] ********************************************************************
ok: [ubuntu] => (item={'key': u'olcLogLevel', 'value': u'none'})

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure enabled services] *************************************************************
changed: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Install ldapscripts packages] ***********************************************************
ok: [ubuntu] => (item=[u'ldapscripts', u'ldap-utils', u'pwgen'])

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure ldapscripts] ******************************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Configure ldapscripts password] *********************************************************
changed: [ubuntu]

TASK [debops.slapd : Create snapshot task in cron] ***********************************************************
ok: [ubuntu]

RUNNING HANDLER [debops.slapd : Restart slapd] ***************************************************************
changed: [ubuntu]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************
ubuntu                     : ok=28   changed=12   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So far, so good but I can't connect to the LDAP directory using the admin user and admin password that has been set as parameters. To test this I have installed a `phpldapadmin` installation on the same machine:

[image: Screenshot of phpldapadmin]

Entering the password `yoh7eQue9Ki0aitee5uquaichuteo0ti` (which is the same as the one in the password file) will always result in "Invalid credentials".

Running `slapcat` shows that the administrator account itself has been created:

```
dn: dc=development,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: development.local
dc: development
structuralObjectClass: organization
entryUUID: 2b111f1a-058f-1037-9bc1-01ccfd85f1f8
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=development,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20170725141325Z
entryCSN: 20170725141325.508993Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=development,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20170725141325Z

dn: cn=admin,dc=development,dc=local
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9S1haVEUvbVQ1U0tBSEU1RXhVYVVhMDM4UGVoSS9ZNVA=
structuralObjectClass: organizationalRole
entryUUID: 2b114558-058f-1037-9bc2-01ccfd85f1f8
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=development,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20170725141325Z
entryCSN: 20170725141325.510040Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=development,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20170725141325Z
```

Any ideas why the authentication fails? Did I use the correct mechanism to pass the password to `debops.slapd`?

Answer (score 1):

The `debops.slapd` role might not be in a working state at the moment; it hasn't been touched for almost a year.

However, DebOps roles usually provide a set of sane default values. Did you try running the role without setting custom values in your own first? The role has [an example playbook](https://github.com/debops/ansible-slapd/blob/master/docs/playbooks/slapd.yml) included, you could try that one and see if the service is configured properly.

To help with debugging,you could use Apache Directory Studio as a low-level LDAP client. The `debops.slapd` role uses the X.509 certificates maintained by the `debops.pki` role; if you use that, you might need to add the Root CA certificate to the ADS certificate store.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The question that remains is: If I do not enter the administrator password manually, then where can I retreive the password that is automatically generated during the installation?

Plus: If the `debops.slapd` role is not in a working state: Can you suggest any alternative in setting up an LDAP server on a target environment?

Comment: The autogenerated passwords are stored in the `secret/` directory which is right next to your Ansible inventory directory. This is managed by the `debops.secret` role, you can check its documentation for the details.

Unfortunately I don't know about any good alternative `slapd` roles. You could check out what doesn't work in `debops.slapd` and post a PR with fixes, if they are needed. At the moment the role lacks some important features, like LDAP database replication, that's planned for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from drybjed I think I was able to find the cause of the problem:

```
...
slapd_config_admin_password: 'passwords/ldap-admin.password'
slapd_basedn_admin_password: 'passwords/ldap-admin.password'
...
```

These are actually **not** the *source* files from which to read the password to be used for slapd but the *target* files in the secret inventory directory into which to write the output of the passwords generated during the installation process of slapd.

After having deleted all the files in `/usr/local/etc/secret/`(I'm using Ansible on macOS installed via Homebrew) and then run the Ansible playbook again the password file for the administrator (cn=admin,dc=development,dc=local) was generated at `/usr/local/etc/secret/ldap/credentials/ldap./cn=admin,dc=.password`.

Using the password stored in this file for logging into LDAP did work correctly.